# Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'idStudent' cannot be null

Tags: laravel, seeders

Tengo dos tablas (students y exams) donde la relación es 1:N. Estoy usando los factories y los seeders de Laravel, ya inserte varios estudiantes y con esos no hay problema, el detalle es con la tabla de examenes.

```
return [
        'subject' => $this->faker->randomElement(['Cálculo', 'Química', 'Programación', 'Física', 'Administración']),
        'question' => 'pregunta ¿?',
        'answer' => $this->faker->sentences(1,true),
        'qualification' => $this->faker->randomElement(['Excelente: 90', 'Bien: 80', 'Regular: 70', 'Repetir']),
        'idStudent' => Student::all()->random(),
    ];
```

1. Busque y según así es como se obtiene un registro de otra tabla pero no funciona:(
2. El campo 'idStudent' es foráneo y hace la referencia a la tabla students (donde surge el problema)
3. También tengo importado el modelo de Student en el archivo ExamFactory.

Cuando ejecuto php artisan db:seed este es el error:

> Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'idStudent' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `exams` (`subject`, `question`, `answer`, `qualification`, `idStudent`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Administración, pregunta ¿?, Repellat quaerat asperiores aut magni., Excelente: 90, ?, 2020-10-11 23:46:36, 2020-10-11 23:46:36))

No entiendo por qué es que no lo obtiene si sí existen registros en la tabla students.

Gracias por su atención!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hacer esto:

```
Student::all()->random()
```

No es el modo adecuado o funcional para insertar de manera *aleatoria* el id de un estudiante en tu otra tabla ¿por qué?, bueno por que el método **`all()`** retorna una colección y entonces cuando haces uso de **`random()`** en la misma query, en realidad lo que obtienes un objeto de esa colección.

Mas o menos así:

```
>>> App\Models\Modelo::all()->random();
=> App\Models\Modelo {#3598
     id: 2,
     atributo1: "valor1",
     atributo2: "valor2",
     ..................
     ..................
   }
>>>
```

Sin embargo, puedes bien considerar alguna de las siguientes opciones:

Dejarlo así como esta pero indicando la propiedad deseada del objeto así:

```
Student::all()->random()->id;
```

O Por el contrario, si lo único que deseas retornar es el id de ese objeto, entonces tu consulta debe ser así:

```
Modelo::inRandomOrder()->first()->id;
```

Donde de acuerdo con [la doc. de laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset) usaremos a **`inRandomOrder()`** para hacer un ordenamiento aleatorio de los resultados, con **`first`** limitamos los resultados al primero obtenido y finalmente indicamos la propiedad que deseamos obtener del modelo en cuestión.

Por cierto también debes declarar en el modelo **`Student`** en el [array de **`$fillable`**](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#mass-assignment) a la propiedad `idStudent` así:

```
class Student extends Model 
{
    protected $fillable = [...................., 'idStudent'];
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por el aporte, ambas me funcionaron pero me quedo con la segunda 